# Python readline module on OS X lacks set_pre_input_hook

Tags: python, macos, readline

I added the following code to my python startup script. It works great on Windows 7 after I install `pyreadline` via pip, but it's not working on OS X Yosemite (10.10.2 to be specific).

```
import readline

def atPrompt():
    import readline
    global freshPrompt
    if freshPrompt:
        freshPrompt = False

    last = readline.get_history_item(readline.get_current_history_length())

    spaces = last[:len(last) - len(last.lstrip())]
    if last.isspace():
        spaces = spaces[:-4]
    elif last and last.strip()[-1] == ':':
        spaces += '    '
    readline.insert_text(spaces)

readline.set_pre_input_hook(atPrompt)

# (I also make it so that when PS1 is called, global freshPrompt is set to True.)
```

This code automatically indents for me when I'm typing in interactive Python. If the prior line I entered ends in a `:`, it automatically indents four extra spaces. If the prior line started with spaces but contained more than just spaces, it lines up the new line with that prior one. If the prior line was nothing but spaces, it dedents the new line for me.

Whereas this code works perfectly for me on Windows (with `pyreadline` from `pip`), it does nothing on OS X. It doesn't tell me about any modules being missing. I use `readline`'s `get_history_item()` and `get_current_history_length()` elsewhere in OS X just fine.

If I insert a `print` statement at the start of `atPrompt`, it never appears in OS X but shows up fine in Windows.

This leads me to think that `set_pre_input_hook()` does nothing in OS X.

I know that the `readline` module in OS X differs from that on other *nix distributions (for licensing reasons). I've heard that it's possible to install the same module on OS X.

But when I try installing `readline` via pip, with

```
pip install readline
```

I get the following errors:

> creating build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7
>
> cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/Modules/2.x/readline.o readline/libreadline.a readline/libhistory.a -lncurses -o build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/readline.so
>
> clang: error: no such file or directory: 'readline/libreadline.a'
>
> clang: error: no such file or directory: 'readline/libhistory.a'
>
> error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
>
> ---
>
> Cleaning up...
>   Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;`__file__`='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/readline/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(`__file__`).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), `__file__`, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-FYqn9p-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/readline
>   Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Taylor/Library/Logs/pip.log

(I added backticks around `__file__` to keep it from being displayed as **file**.)

How do I get `set_pre_input_hook()` to work on OS X? Am I right in thinking I should replace the `readline` module? If so, how do I get it installed, because simply trying to install it via `pip` is resulting in the above error messages.

As an extra detail, the Windows machine is running Python 2.7.8. The OS X machine is running Python 2.7.6.

Comment: It appears there could be incompatibilities -- https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1bb9641713ec/Modules/readline.c#l49 although what you mention here doesn't seem like it would conflict with the comment there ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the best way to do this is to install `gnureadline`.

```
pip install gnureadline
```

Unfortunately, this means for scripts to be compatible across platforms you need to write this:

```
try:
    import gnureadline as readline
except ImportError:
    import readline
```

Instead of just this:

```
import readline
```

If anyone knows a better, less verbose solution for importing, please share it.

Comment: Still the same situation in 2024 with macOS 10.15 Catalina; And the provided trick works with Python 3.11.